# How to implement multiple Try-Catch block inside a For-Loop?

Tags: java, for-loop, exception, multidimensional-array, try-catch

Say I have a 2D array (X by X, X = b.size) and each element inside is an object(Tile Class). I want to use a for-loop to iterate each element(b.tile(i,j)) and see if there's any adjacent element around it that holds the same value (use .value() to get the value). If there's at lease one element around it that holds the same value then return true.

I'm trying to compare its value with adjacent elements(b.tile(i-1,j), b.tile(i+1,j), b.tile(i,j-1), b.tile(i,j+1)) but there'll be indexOutOfBoundException when it comes to elements that are on the array's border. I want to use multiple Try-Catch blocks to handle exception but one exception will stop the iteration and move on to the next, which is not what I want. Since there might be other Try-Catch blocks that return true.

May I receive some pointers?

Here's what I wrote so far:

```
for (int i = 0; i < b.size(); i ++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < b.size(); j ++) {
            try {
                if ((b.tile(i, j).value() == b.tile(i + 1, j).value()) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                continue;
            }
            try {
                if ((b.tile(i, j).value() == b.tile(i - 1, j).value()) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                continue;
            }
            try {
                if ((b.tile(i, j).value() == b.tile(i, j - 1).value()) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                continue;
            }
            try {
                if ((b.tile(i, j).value() == b.tile(i, j + 1).value()) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                continue;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: In general, don't use exceptions for logic control.  Instead, change the `for` to terminate so an exception will not be thrown, for example `for (int i = 0; i < b.size() - 1; i ++)`, and/or explicitly check the boundary in the `if` condition.

Comment: it's not clear what you are trying to achieve. The `continue` statements will continue the loop, not check another part of the `if` logic statements.

Comment: @AndrewS, not in general, NEVER use exceptions for logic control. That said, it doesn't mean that you cannot execute an alternate execution if an exception occurs during normal execution. For example if writing to a new file, it is OK to create a new file if a `FileNotFoundException` is caught.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to use multiple Try-Catch blocks to handle exception but one exception will stop the iteration and move on to the next, which is not what I want

It is not the Try-Catch block that skips you to the next iteration in the loop without evaluating the other Try-Catch blocks, it is the `continue` statement.  If you remove the `continue` and have nothing in your `catch` block, you will get the behavior that you want.

That being said, as Andrew mentioned, Try-Catch blocks and exceptions were not designed for this type of logic and **you should not use them here**.  You should devise a way to check that your index values are within the bounds of your 2D array before you attempt to index into the array at those values.

To give you an idea of what I'm talking about see below

```
    for (int i = 0; i < b.size(); i ++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < b.size(); j ++) {
        if (i + 1 < b.size() && b.tile(i, j).value() == b.tile(i + 1, j).value()) {
          return true;
        }
        if (i - 1 > 0  && (b.tile(i, j).value() == b.tile(i - 1, j).value()) {
          return true;
        }
        if (j - 1 > 0 && (b.tile(i, j).value() == b.tile(i, j - 1).value()) {
          return true;
        }
        if (j + 1 < b.size() && (b.tile(i, j).value() == b.tile(i, j + 1).value()) {
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      }
    }
    return false;
```

Comment: Thank you Ben. Not only it answered my question but also it provided the best practise.